# Access a docker container on a non standard SSL port

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, curl, docker

I'm new to docker and an using v1.8.1 on Ubtuntu 14.04.

I've got Apache setup as a virtual host serving a webite on http://www.domain.com and would like to server [PEPS](https://github.com/MLstate/PEPS) on https://email.domain.com

Note: PEPS only runs on a SSL connection.

I disabled letting apache listen on port 443, as PEPS was complaining that the port is in use.

apache port.conf :

```
Listen 80

#<IfModule ssl_module>
#       Listen 443
#</IfModule>

#<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
#       Listen 443
#</IfModule>
```

I setup a virtual host for port 80 to point to the website directory.
At this point, I am able to access the website at http://www.domain.com and the PEPS container at https://www.domain.com
I can even fetch the PEPS login page via the curl command.

```
curl -vk https://localhost:443
```

In order to serve PEPS on https://mail.domain.com, I'll first need to run PEPS on another port (9091) and then create a reverse proxy for mail.domain.com:443 to point to localhost:9091.

I change the port PEPS runs on in the [makefile](https://github.com/MLstate/PEPS/blob/master/Makefile#L11) and rebuilt/restarted the container. Verified that PEPS was running on 9091 by running

```
netstat -tapen | grep ":9091 "
```

Running the curl command, I see the following error.

```
croydon@vps138520:~/PEPS$ curl -vk https://localhost:9091
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:9091/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9091 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:9091 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:9091
```

Any thoughts as to why this might be? Accessing a container from a non standard SSL port results in an error.

```
croydon@vps138520:~/PEPS$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                       NAMES
238dd721273e        smtpin              "/sbin/my_init"          32 minutes ago      Up 32 minutes       0.0.0.0:25->25/tcp, 0.0.0.0:587->587/tcp    peps_smtpin
603a5dc16a8e        peps                "/sbin/my_init"          32 minutes ago      Up 32 minutes       443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9091->9091/tcp, 8999/tcp   peps_server
4573ee08c153        smtpout             "/sbin/my_init"          32 minutes ago      Up 32 minutes       25/tcp, 0.0.0.0:465->465/tcp                peps_smtpout
028f4b0cb61e        solr                "/bin/bash -c 'cd /op"   32 minutes ago      Up 32 minutes       8983/tcp                                    peps_solr
452c6a557f65        mongod              "/usr/bin/mongod --po"   32 minutes ago      Up 32 minutes       27017/tcp                                   peps_mongod


croydon@vps138520:~$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:9091
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 295 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---

croydon@vps138520:~$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:9091 -ssl3
CONNECTED(00000003)
140545670362784:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:598:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1440181543
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: Something in your SSL stack changed when you changed the port. What do you get when you run `openssl s_client -connect localhost:9091`

Comment: Hi Rico, I've added the result of running that command above. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the SSL certificate.
When I was hosting the container on the public 443 port, the certificate had the domain name of: domain.com.

However, when hosting it on port 9091, I had to create a new certificate with the domain name of: localhost